# Facebook domain insights "add domain" button not working

Tags: facebook

I am attempting to utilize Facebook domain insights. Fb(.)com/insights

When I go to the page and click "add domain" the light box attempts to open but does not. I have tried to login on multiple browsers and have asked others from around the world to try and they are having the same issue.

I have been trying to do this for a few weeks. Am I doing something wrong? Is it broken?

TIA

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be broken for everyone.

Insights for existing domains still work, but adding new ones doesn't.

Since you can't create domain objects via the Graph API and there are no other links pointing to the same functionality you can only file a bug report (even my guess would be that FB already deprecated domain insights).